# How to Register a new OAuth applicationin github

Tags: oauth, prose

I am trying to make a site from code https://github.com/prose/prose
site link is http://editor.jus.in what should be my Homepage URL and Authorization callback URL for this application on https://github.com/settings/applications/new ?

In apps documentation it says

1.Redirect users to request GitHub access.

```
GET https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
```

2.GitHub redirects back to your site including a temporary code you need for the next step.

You can grab it like so:

```
var code = window.location.href.match(/\?code=(.*)/)[1];
```

3.Request the actual token using your instance of Gatekeeper, which knows your client_secret.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:9999/authenticate/'+code, function(data) {
  console.log(data.token);
});
```

Where should I do these changes?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation instead of asking us a vague question?

Comment: Sorry I am newbie, I can't understand that. What the problem is my site redirects back to prose.io not to editor.justinechacko.in

Comment: `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token` Is this the callback url?

Comment: Some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to build master branch locally